# React, Webpack, Stylus - import global variables to all components

Tags: reactjs, webpack, stylus

I have react app and in webpack I have this code:

```
stylus: {
    use: [require('nib'), require('jeet')],
    import: [
        '~nib/lib/nib/index.styl',
        '~jeet/stylus/jeet/_jeet',
        '~rupture/rupture/index.styl'
    ]
}
```

How can I import my `variable.styl` to every component globally? I need add something like this:

```
stylus: {  
    import: [
        './app/styles/variables.styl'
    ]
}
```

after this webpack stopped at 96% and nothing else.

Comment: Can you explain the use-case for this?

Comment: for example from this file: [link] (https://github.com/alejofernandez/react-stylus-webpack-boilerplate/blob/master/src/components/Header/Header.styl) I want to get this **base.styl** `@import "../../theme/base"` to webpack

Comment: So you want the CSS generated from `base.styl` to be included globally (like a regular stylesheet)?

Comment: Yes ..but the method in webpack with configure stylus > import > 'my.styl' doesn't work

Comment: If you're using `style-loader`, `require`'ing (or `import`ing) a style sheet will add a `<link>` element to the DOM, which seems to me is basically what you want. If you do that in a top-level JS file (like [`src/index.js`](https://github.com/alejofernandez/react-stylus-webpack-boilerplate/blob/master/src/index.js) in the project you mentioned), the styles will automatically become available as regular CSS styles. I think the Stylus-import is meant specifically for loading Stylus plugins (however, you could try and see if it works better by providing a full path to `variables.styl`).

Comment: But my `variables.styl` contain only variables that are needed in every component..there is no generated CSS. Therefor i want use import in webpack

Comment: AFAIK, you can't use Stylus variables in Javascript, though. They are only used within Stylus to facilitate generating the resulting CSS.

Comment: It is same as in my first code in this question: `'~nib/lib/nib/index.styl'` and it work..there is no problem with usage variables from nib or jeet or rupture (modules from node_modules) ..But I need import to webpack my custom variables

Comment: Try _adding_ the full path of your `variables.styl` to the `import` array: `path.resolve(__dirname, './app/styles/variables.styl')`

Comment: OH thank you  robertklep ..It work's! You solved my two days dilema :) Thank you very much!

Comment: Good to hear it worked! I'll write up a proper answer, in case other people ever run into the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most paths in the Webpack configuration need to be full paths (absolute, not relative).

Try this:

```
const path = require('path');
...
stylus: {  
  import: [
    '~nib/lib/nib/index.styl',
    '~jeet/stylus/jeet/_jeet',
    '~rupture/rupture/index.styl',
    path.resolve(__dirname, './app/styles/variables.styl')
  ]
}
```

(I think the initial three imports may not be necessary if they also get `@import`'ed in `variables.styl`).

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who are using Webpack 2+, this is the way to go now:

Your `webpack.config.js`

```js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(styl|css)$/,
                use: [
                    'css-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'stylus-loader',
                        options: {
                            import: [
                                path.resolve(__dirname, './app/assets/stylesheets/variables.styl') // Path to the file
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ],
            },            
        ],
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `style-resources-loader` to inject global variables for you *.styl files.